# Internal JSON-RPC error with MetaMask on Polygon Blockchain. `ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved.`

Tags: blockchain, polygon, solidity, metamask, erc721

I am making an NFT marketplace. When I deployed my contract on the Mumbai-testnet. The createToken function might work cause it brings up the Metamask for the Gas Fee but after that, the Error occurs something regarding the **ONWNERSHIP**.
*(Error image and text is present below.)*

**STEPS which I follow**

1. `npm hardhat node`
2. `npm run dev`
3. Selecting the Creating Page.
4. Enter all the details.
5. Click on Create an Asset which calls the **createToken** function.

then the error occurs.

**Here is my NFT contract**

```
contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
address contractAddress;

constructor(address marketplaceAddress) ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "METT") {
    contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
}

function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

    _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
    setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);

    return newItemId;
}}
```

**Here is my NFTMarket contract**

```
contract NFTMarket is ReentrancyGuard {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
Counters.Counter private _itemSold;

address payable owner;
uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether; // Here ether is denoting the MATIC

constructor() {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
}

struct MarketItem {
    uint256 itemId;
    address nftContract;
    uint256 tokenId;
    address payable seller;
    address payable owner;
    uint256 price;
    bool sold;
}

mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

event MarketItemCreated(
    uint256 indexed itemId,
    address indexed nftContract,
    uint256 indexed tokenId,
    address seller,
    address owner,
    uint256 price,
    bool sold
);

function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    return listingPrice;
}

//Function to create an NFT
function createMarketItem(
    address nftContract,
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 price
) public payable nonReentrant {
    //Conditions for creating the Item.
    require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
    require(
        msg.value == listingPrice,
        "Price must be equal to listing price"
    );

    _itemIds.increment();
    uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();

    idToMarketItem[itemId] = MarketItem(
        itemId,
        nftContract,
        tokenId,
        payable(msg.sender),
        payable(address(0)), // When new NFT is created its ownership add is set to 0.
        price,
        false
    );

    IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

    //Trigger the Event
    emit MarketItemCreated(
        itemId,
        nftContract,
        tokenId,
        msg.sender,
        address(0),
        price,
        false
    );
}

//Function to Transfer the Ownership
function createMarketSale(address nftContract, uint256 itemId)
    public
    payable
    nonReentrant
{
    uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
    uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;

    require(
        msg.value == price,
        "Please submit the asking value in order to Purchase"
    );

    //Will transfer the MATIC to the seller address.
    idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);

    //Will transfer the ownership from the owner of this contract to the Buyer.
    IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

    //Set the local value of the owner to the Buyer(msg.sender).
    idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);

    //Set this NFT as sold.
    idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
    _itemSold.increment();

    payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
}

//Returns number of items unsold
function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint256 itemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint256 unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemSold.current();
    uint256 currentIndex = 0;

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)) {
            uint256 currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
    }
    return items;
}

//Returns number of Own(Created or Bought) NFTs
function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint256 totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint256 itemCount = 0;
    uint256 currentIndex = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
            itemCount += 1;
        }
    }

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
            uint256 currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
    }
    return items;
}

//Returns the no of NFT created
function fetchItemsCreated() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint256 totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint256 itemCount = 0;
    uint256 currentIndex = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
            itemCount += 1;
        }
    }

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
            uint256 currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
    }
    return items;
}}
```

I tried changing the RPC in the MetaMask and the configuration files and redeployed it many times with different accounts, but still, nothing changes.

**The Error**

```
 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. 
data:
code: 3
message: "execution reverted: ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
```

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qhk3.jpg)

**If any other info is required please comment**

[Link of Blockchain Explorer](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x785c753671255182d088898a1fcf220ab60db8f4aa000f41891b80bc6414c29f)

Comment: Can you link the failing transaction on a blockchain explorer?

Comment: Done sir, edited.
In my opinion it create the token id but the approval is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However the linked transaction is not failing. Can you provide steps to reproduce the error message (such as what function, from which address, which token ID, ...)?

Comment: Sir, I have updated the Query and put the image of the console there. I hope this may provide you the complete info. If anything left please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You for your efforts.
I got the solution to it(After Searching for 3 days).

**SOLUTION**=>

There's currently a bug on Mumbai causing deployed addresses to be incorrect. This is causing the constructor of the **NFT** contract to approve the **wrong address** for NFT purchases (because it uses the address of the Market deployment for approval) — causing the annoying `"execution reverted: ERC721: approve caller is not owner nor approved for all"` error.

Try using **Mainnet** (yes, you'll have to use real money) but it works!

[Reference](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/2162)

Here's a workaround deploy script that will make it work on Mumbai. Replace main() in deploy.js with:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  console.log(
    "Deploying contracts with the account:",
    deployer.address
  );

  let txHash, txReceipt
  const NFTMarket = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarket");
  const nftMarket = await NFTMarket.deploy();
  await nftMarket.deployed();

  txHash = nftMarket.deployTransaction.hash;
  txReceipt = await ethers.provider.waitForTransaction(txHash);
  let nftMarketAddress = txReceipt.contractAddress

  console.log("nftMarket deployed to:", nftMarketAddress);

  const NFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  const nft = await NFT.deploy(nftMarketAddress);
  await nft.deployed();


  txHash = nft.deployTransaction.hash;
  // console.log(`NFT hash: ${txHash}\nWaiting for transaction to be mined...`);
  txReceipt = await ethers.provider.waitForTransaction(txHash);
  let nftAddress = txReceipt.contractAddress

  console.log("nft deployed to:", nftAddress);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**Redeploy the Contracts** with this Script, and change the `config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your full code and it is working.

You are inheriting from `ERC721URIStorage` which inherits from `ERC721` If you check the `transferFrom` inside `ERC721`:

```
function transferFrom(address from,address to,uint256 tokenId
        ) public virtual override {
        // *****  THIS REQUIRE IS NOT SATISFIED *****
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

you are getting that error, because `require` statement inside `transferFrom` is not satisfied.

this is the `_isApprovedOrOwner`

```
 function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
    }
```

this function is not returning `True`. in order to get `True`, this

```
spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender)
```

should return True. in `or` operations in order to get True, 3 of conditions must be `True`.

In my opinion, you are trying to transfer a token that is not yours.

Comment: I did use the second statement to transfer from. I have added my MARKET CONTRACT please have a look. And if any other info require let me know.

Comment: when do u get the error. while you compile or you are calling from frontend

Comment: When I call from the frontend.

Comment: I have step by step checked the code 4 5 times with the Youtube I have practising from. There is no difference in code, still I am getting this unknown issue.

Comment: share the front-end code please. your contract code looks ok

Comment: Thank You for your efforts, I got the solution and posted it in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

During development, every time you compile your smart contract (using something like `hardhat compile..`) , you have to copy the new smart contract addresses generated in your command prompt and paste them in the designated location in your source code.